# Error StartTag: invalid element name al crear XML

Tags: php, xml

El error está dentro de este esquema que es el que uso para los artículos:

```
echo "<url>\n";
          echo "<loc>http://www.miweb.com\noticia/" . $articulo['ID'] . "/" . limpia_url($articulo['titulo']) . "/</loc>\n";
          echo "<news:news>\n";
            echo "<news:publication>\n";
              echo "<news:name>LaXtore<\news:name>\n";
              echo "<news:language>es<\news:language>\n";
            echo "<\news:publication>\n";
            echo "<news:genres>Tecnología, Xbox One, videojuegos, videogames<\news:genres>\n";
            echo "<news:publication_date>" . substr($articulo['fecha_publicacion'],0,10) . "<\news:publication_date>\n";
            echo "<news:title>" . $articulo['titulo'] . "<\news:title>\n";
            echo "<news:keywords>" . str_replace(",", ";",$articulo['etiquetas']) . "<\news:keywords>\n";
          echo "<\news:news>\n";
        echo "</url>\n";
```

Concretamente me dice lo siguiente:

> error on line 46 at column 20: StartTag: invalid element name

que corresponde con esta linea:

```
 echo "<news:name>LaXtore<\news:name>\n";
```

Comment: ¿Qué programa da este error, PHP en el servidor o el navegador leyendo el resultado del programa PHP?

Comment: Entrando directamente en el fichero desde la URL. Pero ya lo he corregido, éste problema, tengo otro. El problema es que les cierre de las etiquetas estaba con `\` cuando debe ser `/`.

Comment: Te recomendaría que utilizaras http://php.net/manual/es/book.simplexml.php o http://php.net/manual/es/book.xmlwriter.php para construir XML con PHP en lugar de concatenar strings porque si utilizaras estas APIs no tendrías problemas con el formato de etiquetas.